# Formatting the way stylesheets are enqueued using wp_enqueue_style

Tags: wordpress-theming

When using `wp_register_style` & `wp_enqueue_style`, WordPress outputs the style path in the header.

What I wanted to know is whether there is a way to format this better so that my source code can be formatted in a way I want.

I am using this:

```
wp_register_style( 'layout', get_template_directory_uri() . '/library/css/layout.css', array(), '2.1', 'all' ); 
wp_enqueue_style( 'layout' );
```

The output of this is:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='layout-css' href='http://localhost/dreamsmedia/wp-content/themes/dreamsmedia/library/css/layout.css?ver=2.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Is there a way to add extra spacing before the output?

Comment: This question really belongs on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is there a way to move the question to WordPress.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer thanks to Justin Tadlock.

`
add_filter( 'style_loader_tag', 'my_style_loader_tag' );

function my_style_loader_tag( $tag ) {
    return "\t" . $tag;
}`

Answer (score 0):

When using either of those API functions, you're relinquishing control to WordPress for writing them out to the browser.

This is the correct way to do it, though.

Additionally, if you look at [the source code](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/functions.wp-styles.php#L0) for the function, you'll notice that there are no calls to `apply_filters` so you're unable to provide any kind of customization to what WordPress does when writing these out.